# The characteristic function induced by L^1 convergence function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Assume $f_n\in L^1(\Omega)$, $f\in L^1(\Omega)$, and $f_n\to f$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset R^N$ is open.

Define
$$ E_t^n:=\{x\in\Omega, f_n(x)>t\}.$$
Hence we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\chi_{E_t^n}(x)-\chi_{E_t}(x)|dt = |f_n(x)-f(x)|.
\end{equation}
I wish to prove, up to reindexing subsequence, that
$$ \chi_{E_t^n}\to \chi_{E_t}$$
in $L^1(\Omega)$ for $\mathcal{L}^1$ a.e. $t$.

I got from 2nd equality that 
$$\int_\Omega |f_n(x)-f(x)| dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_\Omega|\chi_{E_t^n}(x)-\chi_{E_t}(x)|dxdt$$
By taking $n\to\infty$, I think, but i am not sure (may be by dominate?), that I can have
$$0= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\Omega|\chi_{E_t^n}(x)-\chi_{E_t}(x)|dxdt$$
From here I kinda think I should have my conclusion but I am not sure, again... I wish to have a rigors prove.
Any hint or help is really welcome!

Update:

From the answer below @Mustafa, I could improve what I wrote above.By Fatou, I have
$$0= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_\Omega|\chi_{E_t^n}(x)-\chi_{E_t}(x)|dxdt\geq \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\Omega|\chi_{E_t^n}(x)-\chi_{E_t}(x)|dxdt$$

However, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\Omega|\chi_{E_t^n}(x)-\chi_{E_t}(x)|dx$ is always non-negative and we may obtain
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\Omega|\chi_{E_t^n}(x)-\chi_{E_t}(x)|dx =0$$
for a.e. $t$.

Am I done here? Looks to me that I proved the original sequence $f_n$ has the property that 
$$ \chi_{E_t^n}\to \chi_{E_t}$$
in $L^1(\Omega)$ for $\mathcal{L}^1$ a.e. $t$. However, in literature it states that this is only true for a subsequence.

So, where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It remains to justify the interchanging the limit and integral in your last equation and then just apply Fatou's lemma.

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int \int_{\Omega}|\chi_{E_t^n}(x) - \chi_{E_t}(x) |dx dt$

The limit and integral can be interchanged by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I don't really understand what you wrote here. You said by dominated, then what should be the dominate function? Also, where can I obtain my subsequence?

Answer (score 0):

The step in the "Update" section where you claimed to use Fatou's lemma to interchange limit and integration is not accurate. $\lim$ should be replaced by $\liminf$.

Here is what you could do:

Set $$\phi_n(t) = \int_\Omega |\chi_{E_t^n}(x)-\chi_{E_t}(x)|dx.$$

Then, by assumption, we have

$$\phi_n(t)\rightarrow\phi(t)$$
in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Now, recall that $L^1$ convergence implies subsequential a.e. pointwise convergence, which in our setting, exactly means a.e. $L^1$ convergence for the characteristic functions.